# Clean table with \n within a BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I extracted a table from a beautifulSoup object that start such as

```
<html><body><p>{"datasets":{"cf":"</p><table class="fs-table" id="cf-table">\n                    <tbody>\n                        <tr class="thead"><td></td><td>...
```

The "\n             " is messing up with my table when trying to transform it to a dataframe

I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    cleanSoup = BeautifulSoup(str(soup).replace("\n                    ", ""))
    table = cleanSoup.find_all('table')[0]
```

But it does not work.. any idea on how could I get rid of the \n ?? 
Thx you

Comment: Could you specify, what exactly is not working? `replace` _should_ replace whatever  pretty well. It doesn't in your case? Or, could it be that table gets messed because of something else?

Comment: can you share the url and what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the data with '\n' and then strip white spaces and then join.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmldata='''<html><body><p>{"datasets":{"cf":"</p>
<table class="fs-table" id="cf-table">\n                    <tbody>\n                        <tr class="thead"><td></td><td>...'''

htmldata="".join(item.strip() for item in htmldata.split("\n"))

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
print(table)
```

Output:

```
<table class="fs-table" id="cf-table"><tbody><tr class="thead"><td></td><td>...</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `re` module:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r"\n {1,}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
cleanSoup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub(rx, "", str(soup)))
table = cleanSoup.find_all('table')[0]
```